# How to get a process working dir on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to get a process working dir on Windows using native API (for another process using process handle or PID)? I've watched [Process and Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [PSAPI Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and haven't found. Maybe WMI?

Also, regarding these topics, how *PSAPI* relates to *Process and Thread Functions*? Is it outdated?

Comment: Why do I feel the words "How to get process working dir" needs an "a" or "the current" inserted so as to radically clarify this question's intentions?

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, this is my mistake. English isn't my native language (I'm Russian and live in Russia), so I don't know it perfectly well.

Comment: One approach would be to inject a DLL into the process calling GetCurrentDirectory on your behalf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need heavier artillery than PSAPI for this. Here's how to do it (x86 assumed, error handling omitted):

```
ProcessBasicInformation     pbi ;
RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS upp ;
PEB   peb ;
DWORD len ;

HANDLE handle = OpenProcess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid) ;

NtQueryInformationProcess (handle, 0 /*ProcessBasicInformation*/, &pbi,
    sizeof (ProcessBasicInformation), &len) ;

ReadProcessMemory (handle, pbi.PebBaseAddress,    &peb, sizeof (PEB), &len) ;
ReadProcessMemory (handle, peb.ProcessParameters, &upp, sizeof (RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS), &len) ;

WCHAR path = new WCHAR[upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Length / 2 + 1] ;

ReadProcessMemory (handle, upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Buffer, path, upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Length, &len) ;

// null-terminate
path[upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Length / 2] = 0 ;
```

Note that this approach contains a race unless the process is suspended.

Comment: This is a really heavy artillery. Are there no simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Anton's answer, because you can't simply call `NtQueryInformationProcess` like you would a normal function, you have to call the Windows ntdll.dll via `GetModuleHandleW` like so:

getcwd.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cwchar>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

using std::string;
using std::wstring;
using std::vector;
using std::size_t;

// define process_t type
typedef DWORD process_t;

// #define instead of typedef to override
#define RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR struct {\
  WORD Flags;\
  WORD Length;\
  ULONG TimeStamp;\
  STRING DosPath;\
}\

// #define instead of typedef to override
#define RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS struct {\
  ULONG MaximumLength;\
  ULONG Length;\
  ULONG Flags;\
  ULONG DebugFlags;\
  PVOID ConsoleHandle;\
  ULONG ConsoleFlags;\
  PVOID StdInputHandle;\
  PVOID StdOutputHandle;\
  PVOID StdErrorHandle;\
  UNICODE_STRING CurrentDirectoryPath;\
  PVOID CurrentDirectoryHandle;\
  UNICODE_STRING DllPath;\
  UNICODE_STRING ImagePathName;\
  UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;\
  PVOID Environment;\
  ULONG StartingPositionLeft;\
  ULONG StartingPositionTop;\
  ULONG Width;\
  ULONG Height;\
  ULONG CharWidth;\
  ULONG CharHeight;\
  ULONG ConsoleTextAttributes;\
  ULONG WindowFlags;\
  ULONG ShowWindowFlags;\
  UNICODE_STRING WindowTitle;\
  UNICODE_STRING DesktopName;\
  UNICODE_STRING ShellInfo;\
  UNICODE_STRING RuntimeData;\
  RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR DLCurrentDirectory[32];\
  ULONG EnvironmentSize;\
}\

// shortens a wide string to a narrow string
static inline string shorten(wstring wstr) {
  int nbytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), (int)wstr.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  vector<char> buf(nbytes);
  return string { buf.data(), (size_t)WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr.c_str(), (int)wstr.length(), buf.data(), nbytes, NULL, NULL) };
}

// checks whether process handle is 32-bit or not
static inline bool IsX86Process(HANDLE process) {
  BOOL isWow = true;
  SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo = { 0 };
  GetNativeSystemInfo(&systemInfo);
  if (systemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL)
    return isWow;
  IsWow64Process(process, &isWow);
  return isWow;
}

// helper to open processes based on pid with full debug privileges
static inline HANDLE OpenProcessWithDebugPrivilege(process_t pid) {
  HANDLE hToken;
  LUID luid;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);
  tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
  tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tkp, sizeof(tkp), NULL, NULL);
  CloseHandle(hToken);
  return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
}

// helper to get wide character string of pids cwd based on handle
static inline wchar_t *GetCurrentWorkingDirectoryW(HANDLE proc) {
  PEB peb;
  SIZE_T nRead;
  ULONG res_len = 0;
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
  RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS upp;
  HMODULE p_ntdll = GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");
  typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *tfn_qip)(HANDLE, PROCESSINFOCLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);
  tfn_qip pfn_qip = tfn_qip(GetProcAddress(p_ntdll, "NtQueryInformationProcess"));
  NTSTATUS status = pfn_qip(proc, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &res_len);
  if (status) { return NULL; } 
  ReadProcessMemory(proc, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), &nRead);
  if (!nRead) { return NULL; }
  ReadProcessMemory(proc, peb.ProcessParameters, &upp, sizeof(upp), &nRead);
  if (!nRead) { return NULL; }
  PVOID buffer = upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Buffer;
  USHORT length = upp.CurrentDirectoryPath.Length;
  wchar_t *res = new wchar_t[length / 2 + 1];
  ReadProcessMemory(proc, buffer, res, length, &nRead);
  if (!nRead) { return NULL; }
  res[length / 2] = 0;
  return res;
}

// get cwd of pid as a narrow string
string cwd_from_pid(process_t pid) {
  string cwd;
  // open process of pid using full debug privilege
  HANDLE proc = OpenProcessWithDebugPrivilege(pid);
  wchar_t *wcwd = NULL;
  if (IsX86Process(GetCurrentProcess())) {
    if (IsX86Process(proc)) {
      wcwd = GetCurrentWorkingDirectoryW(proc);
    }
  } else {
    if (!IsX86Process(proc)) {
      wcwd = GetCurrentWorkingDirectoryW(proc);
    }
  }
  if (wcwd != NULL) {
    // converts to UTF-8
    cwd = shorten(wcwd);
    // free memory
    delete[] wcwd; 
  }
  // adds trailing slash if one doesn't yet exist or leave empty
  return (cwd.back() == '\\' || cwd.empty()) ? cwd : cwd + "\\";
  // return cwd; // or get the directories completely unmodified
}

// test function (can be omitted)
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc == 2) {
    printf("%s", cwd_from_pid(stoul(string(argv[1]), nullptr, 10)).c_str());
    printf("%s", "\r\n");
  } else {
    printf("%s", cwd_from_pid(GetCurrentProcessId()).c_str());
    printf("%s", "\r\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

buildx86.sh

```
cd "${0%/*}"
g++ getcwd.cpp -o getcwd.exe -std=c++17 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -m32
```

buildx64.sh

```
cd "${0%/*}"
g++ getcwd.cpp -o getcwd.exe -std=c++17 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -m64
```

Beware, this uses a private API which is subject to change without warning and therefore will stop working without notice nor any documentation beforehand. The calling process/exe needs to be the same architecture as the target for this approach to work. Otherwise, it will return an empty string.

If you know how to read printed output from CreateProcess() you may launch the CLI executable of the appropriate architecture based on the architecture of the target executable. That would mean relying on more than one executable for your project to be built, which is slow, but depending on your use case, it can still be acceptable. Obviously, it wouldn't be ideal unless you are creating a new process every so often for this, (not *too* often), shouldn't slow down your program too much.

Answer (score -4):

`"."` is always the current directory. I think it will work.

Comment: Sorry for inexact question, I meant "another process".

Answer (score -4):

Breaking down your question into multiple questions:

> How to get a process working dir on Windows?

This does not referer to a remote process, so for the current process:

`NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->CurrentDirectory.DosPath`

> How to get a process working dir on Windows using native API (for
> another process using process handle or PID)?

This can be achieved by several known and unknown (undocumented) methods and functions. I will leave the undocumented methods out for now and provide you just documented functions.

- By process handle: [GetFinalPathNameByHandleA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea), [GetProcessImageFileNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea), [QueryFullProcessImageNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- By process name: [GetFullPathNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea)
- By Process PID: [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) + [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa)

Comment: The question asks how to get the current directory for another process, not for the current process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston In that case (I didn't notice that part), I will update my answer with a better one. Still, too much ugly code around :)

Comment: @Mecanik Can you update your answer ?